# Rewrite Old dynamic URL to new Dynamic URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My website was using the below URL format

localhost/loc-New-Delhi-India (loc - was common in all URLs and the text after it used to change)

Now, I have changed it to

localhost/New-Delhi-India/location (Removed the loc and placed it at the end of URL as 'location'). For this, I'm using the below rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(location)?$ city-detail.php?cityurl=$1
```

cityurl grabs the string after 'localhost' and searches the db.

Now since the website is heavily indexed by Google and shared a lot on social media, I want to redirect those urls to the new URLs. I tried the below code, but this just doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "loc-(.*)" "^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(location)?$ city-detail.php?cityurl=$1" [R]
```

The new URLs are created successfully, but the old one's fail to redirect to the new one. I'm sure something's wrong but cannot find it. I researched the old questions but they are a bit different. Here, I'm not including any subdirectory after localhost and adding a directory 'localhost' after the city name.

Any help will be appreciated a lott :)

Comment: I don‘t see how `RewriteRule "loc-(.*)" "^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(location)?$ city-detail.php?cityurl=$1" [R]` is supposed to make any sense. What are those weirdly placed quotes supposed to achieve?

Comment: I read it here - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html. But this didn't work

Comment: Place `RewriteRule ^loc-([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/location [L,NC,R=301]` just below `RewriteEngine on` line and test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Yes, the parts (pattern, replacement) can be quoted. But using a regexp character class _in the replacement_ makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It resolved the issue. I tried this earlier but my regexp was a little different. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would probably work:

```
RewriteRule loc-(.*) $1/location [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(location)?$ city-detail.php?cityurl=$1
```

The first rule will trigger a 301 redirect which will also tell any search engines that your resource has been permanently moved and that would probably make them change their indexes to reflect this. Once you've redirected the 2nd rule should trigger as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I actually thought of this logic that a redirect will allow the rule beneath it to run. However, that didn't work. But with this one, I was able to reach to the redirect page and wasn't redirected to the new URL. The second rule didn't trigger.